# bash script error: file or directory doesnt exist

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04

This is my first time writing a bash script.

Here it is:

```
#!/bin/bash       

${file}="/home/isra/files/mongoTemp.json"
${fdiff}="/home/isra/files/mTempDiff.json"
.
.
commands
.
.
        mv ${file} ${fileold}
.
.
commands
.
.
exit
```

But it gives me these two errors:

```
./index.sh: line 4: =$HOME/files/mongoTemp.json: No such file or directory
./index.sh: line 5: =$HOME/files/mTempDiff.json: No such file or directory
mv: missing file operand
couldn't open [$HOME/files/]
```

Honestly, I'm not quiet sure what the problem is.. The files do exist, I've manually created them when it first complained about them but it didn't solve the problem and also, the `mv` command is not working. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When assigning to variables, use `foo=`, and not `$foo=`, or `${foo}=`

I.e., the lines:

```
${file}="/home/isra/files/mongoTemp.json"
${fdiff}="/home/isra/files/mTempDiff.json"
```

Should be:

```
file="/home/isra/files/mongoTemp.json"
fdiff="/home/isra/files/mTempDiff.json"
```

The rest looks fine.

---

Note that the two first errors are because of the `${..}=...` lines.

The variables `$file` and `$fdiff` are empty, which then cause the `mv` error `"mv: missing file operand"`. Some later command you haven't shown causes the final error. Though, most likely, everything will be fixed by properly assigning the variables.